# Segmentation fault (core dumped) linux

Tags: c++, linux

My program is running fine when i run it on VS with my own 'main()' function but i have to submit this where main is hidden from me I only know that it will pass arguements to my functions and check their return result. But it is giving segmentation fault error when I try to use arguement passed to my function.
Here is the code:

```
//I don't know what 'main' is passing to this function

string ExpressionManager::infixToPostfix(string infixExpression)
{   

cout<<infixExpression<<endl; // first it was giving error on below 'if' condition,  
    //now i have written this statement it prints nothing but gives 
     //Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error here

cout<<"Hey"<<endl //it doesn't print this line

if( infixExpression[0] == '\0' )
{
    return "";
}
int size = infixExpression.length();
if(!isValidInfixExpression(infixExpression))
    return "Invalid Expression";
      ...
      //some code here
}
```

Can Anyone Elaborate when string class behave this way?

Comment: Can you show the string being passed to ExpressionManager::infixToPostfix ?

Comment: Main Problem is it is running on an automated checking system so i have no idea what is being passed to this function. And I don't know any scenario in which string class behave this way.

Comment: If you want to see your output in a program-crashing situation like this, you **must** use `cerr`, not `cout`. `cout` is buffered, and there's no telling how much output is abandoned in its buffer when a program crashes.

Comment: Maybe your string isn't actually a string? This could happen if the stack got corrupted, or the caller is passing you the dereference of a valid pointer to something else.

Comment: any example to elaborate your arguement?

Comment: `int i; inFixToPostFix(std::string(*((char*)&i));` is an example of passing the dereference of a valid pointer to something else. `std::string s; memset(&s, 1, 100); inFixToPostFix(s);` is an example of corrupting a string on the stack and passing it to you. Both examples are contrived, of course. These things usually happen in more subtle ways.

Answer (score 0):

The program will crash if an empty string is passed to the method. You should check the size of the string before the statement `if( infixExpression[0] == '\0' )`. Instead of this condition you can use `if(infixExpression.size()==0)` or `if(infixExpression.empty())` etc.

Edit:

The follwing code will lead to crash right before the function call:

```
              string* s= NULL;
              infixExpression(*s);
```

This is because the while calling the function, the parameter will be copied using the copy constructor of the object, but the object does not exist.

Comment: But if the string is empty then it should not give segmentation fault error on 'cout' statement before 'if' condition.

Comment: @user3592832 An empty string is a valid string; there's no problem outputting it.  On the other hand, it's very strange to compare the contents of a string to `'\0'`; this sort of test is usually only used on '\0' terminated strings.  (An `std::string` can contain a `'\0'`.)

Comment: If you look my code closely, I mentioned there it never reaches 'if' condition, it gives error on the very first line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your problem. Try the following code:

```
string *p_to_void;
cout << *p_to_void;
```

The code above will definitely cause segmentation fault due to uninitialized pointer. Even if the pointer is initialized, it could point to NULL which will also cause a segfault.An empty string does NOT cause the problem but an uninitialized pointer does.

Comment: Yes you are ri8, but the thing is if main is passing uninitialized pointer then it should never enter my function, because it will not be able to copy into my function parameter but it is entering into the function.

Comment: It's possible to copy a null object into your function. I have written a sample code that works in this way.
void will_crash(string s){
    cout << s << endl;
}
int main(){
    string *p_to_void = NULL;
    will_crash(*p_to_void);
}

Comment: share code with me so that i can understand it better.

Comment: Sorry, my formatting is awful. There's even no newline allowed in the comment section?!

Comment: if you write 'cout<<"Hey"<<endl;' before 'cout<<s<<endl;' in your function then you will see it never enters into your function it simply generate error on the header.

Comment: hmmm. You are right. According to GDB, the error was captured in  `std::basic_string` instead of at the line where cout presents. My guess is that the copy constructor was somehow screwed by our code.

Comment: Yeah! But in the above code of mine, it enter into function but when i am trying to print or access it, it generates Segmentation fault error.